# how to manage hide and show multiple div and sections using jquery

Tags: javascript

I have many charts and cards,in my layout,when the page loads i dont want to see them before my filter button is clicked,the way i am doing is i set their display to none,and when i press the filter i show them,it works fine,but since i am new in js and css,i was wondering if there is a better way to manage it,

```
<div id="gridID" class="card chartsGridhights" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">
    <div id="pieChartID" class="card" style="float:left;width:20%;display:none">
        <div id="faultStatChartID" class="card" style="width:55%;float:right;margin-right:2%;display:none;">
            <div id="btnCurrentStatID" class="card" style="float:right;width:20%;height:350px;display:none;">
```

in javascript:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function() {
    $("#btnCurrentStatID").css("display", "block");
    $("#faultStatChartID").css("display", "block");
    $("#pieChartID").css("display", "block");
    $("#gridID").css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: You can wrap them in a div and show/hide that. jQuery also has `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class, say, `.hideShow` in the elements on which you want to hide or show them in the HTML. Change your code to:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="gridID" class="card chartsGridhights hideShow" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">
  <div id="pieChartID" class="card hideShow" style="float:left;width:20%;display:none">
  <div id="faultStatChartID" class="card hideShow" style="width:55%;float:right;margin-right:2%;display:none;">
  <div id="btnCurrentStatID" class="card hideShow" style="float:right;width:20%;height:350px;display:none;">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function () {          
     $(".hideShow").css("display", "block");
     //or $(".hideShow").show();
});
```

Using `class` selector is more flexible and reduce a large number of code as compared to using an `id` selector for display block in your case.

Comment: thanks,this is perfect,but if i want to specifically hide one of them,then i should use id,right?

Comment: @mrslt yes, you can first show all the elements using the `class` selector then below this code hide the element using `id` selector.

Comment: @mrslt you can upvote and accept the answer if this was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use below script

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function() {
    $(".card").hide();
    $("SHOWCLASSID").show();
});
```

Comment: Use classes to hide/show when you are trying to do for multiple div's. When we have single div to hide you can use 'id'.

Comment: please share your button code on which are you clicking

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding by id, you could hide by class - in which case you wont have to write / update each time there is a new ID. So, for example

```
<div id="gridID" class="card chartsGridhights someidentifier" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">

<div id="gridID" class="card chartsGridhights someidentifier" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">
```

you can then simply apply the hide and show on the someidentifier or someotheridentifier $('.someidentifier')......

Also, I see you are using inline styles - it is better to avoid inline styles.

Finally - you can use a jQuery plugin like Shuffle, Sortable etc... simply search for a jQuery filter plugin and you will see a whole list for you to choose from.

Most plugins have a forum where you can discuss any issues you may face.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using inline style as it increase the page size. Remove `inline display: none` and add `.hide` class to all `div` and remove that when you click on button

CSS

```
.hide {display: none}
```

HTML

```
<div id="gridID" class="hide card chartsGridhights" style="width:49%;float:left">
      <div id="pieChartID" class="hide card" style="float:left;width:20%">
      <div id="faultStatChartID" class="hide card" style="width:55%;float:right;margin-right:2%;">
      <div id="btnCurrentStatID" class="hide card" style="float:right;width:20%;height:350px;">
```

Jquery

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function () {          
     $("div").removeClass("hide");
});
```